# Kruskal's algorithm - optimal way to keep nodes

Tags: algorithm, nodes, kruskals-algorithm

Like in title. What is the optimal way to keep nodes in memory for Kruskal's algorithm, and why?

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kruskal algorithm is basically dong exactly what the [Disjoint set forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests) structure is meant to do. This structure starts with all nodes being in separate components and then supports operations of the kind

> Join nodes A and B

and

> Are Nodes A and B in the same cover tree already?

That is exactly why I would tell this is the most suitable representation for the nodes.